# Cookie set when I'm using graphiql but not when I'm using my frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, graphql

I'm trying to save my token in a cookie in my backend.
when I'm checking my function with graphiql, the token saves and I'm getting it when I ask it (context.cookies.token). But then I try it from my frontend, and the cookie doesn't save (and doesn't appear in my dev-tools -> application). And when I try to get it with context.cookies.token I got undefined.

my login function (Here I want to save my token on a cookie and use it in other function, but for this time I'm checking all the process in this function)

```html
const login = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
    coenter code herenst sql = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "${args.username}"`;
    const results = await context.dbService.runSQL(sql);
    const user = results[0]
    if (!user) throw new Error('Invalid username or password');
    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(args.password, user.password);
    if (!valid) throw new Error('Invalid username or password');
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, APP_SECRET);
    context.res.cookie('token', token, {maxAge: 3600000});
    console.log('cookies', context.cookies.token);
    return {
        token,
        user
    };
};
```

At the two last lines before the return I'm saving the token - this line works only when I check it in the graphiql tool.
And try to get it from "req.cookies.token" (The context includes all the req properties), In graphiql, I'm getting here the token, when the req is from frontend I got undefined

please help me to solve that.
I tried it with async-await and without, with httpOnly and without.
my backend is running on localhost:3030 and my frontend on localhost:3000.
I'm opening my localhost:3030 and do not see anything in my dev-tools -> application -> cookies.

Thanks!

Comment: That means your frontend might not accept cross-domain cookies. GraphiQL runs on 3030 as well, right?

Comment: CORS is not a problem when resolver is called (?) ... frontend (react?/apollo client?) should be configured to use cookies (credentials: "include",)

Comment: I tried to use credentials: "same-origin" and "include" but doesn't help. In my backend I  set the CORS to allow my frontend path, So I don't get CORS problem

Comment: @Bergi I guess that it works when I'm using graphiql because of it is on the same origin / path / port.. But I don't find the solution

Comment: generally compare with graphiql request headers ... many reasons ...         https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4190 - choose your problem

Comment: @xadm frontend with React and Apollo client.

Comment: @xadm thanks! I found it with your credentials: 'include' advice.